# Control not returning after executing terminal command in python 2.7

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

```
import os
os.system("omxplayer music.mp3")
print('hello')
```

Control isn't returning after executing omx player, and it doesn't prints hello. Also I tried using `subprocess.Popen()` or `run` but its not even executing the command. Need help. I'm doing it on raspberry pi 3 with raspbian. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does omxplayer terminate?

Comment: What does omxplayer do? I guess it would not exit until the music is finished and that's why you can't see `os.system` return.

Comment: I don't know if it terminates or not. But it plays the sound and if I run on terminal, it just works fine. Plays and exits.

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data. I’m curious, why are you using Python 2?